# optimal solution for filtering inherited django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a generic scenario but I put it specific to make it easy to answer.

I have model Image which has fields for name, url, camera, format, created_date, uploaded_date, and some more. (these are the EXIF info. would have preferred a manytomany field for these as tags but I worried it gets too complicated.)

I have another model File, which has a foreignkey Image field and a foreignkey User field. (if two different Users have the same Image, there will be one Image object and two File objects for the Users directing to that Image.)

Now there are two tasks I need to perform. 1- find all different cameras a User has. (or formats, etc.) 2- filter all of the User Files by a specific camera.

I can't figure out the more efficient artitecture for this case.

Thanks so much for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your File model is actually a custom many to many relationship. I would use a ManyToMany in the Image model to the user model.

```
class Image(models.Model):
   ...
   users = models.ManyToManyField(...)
```

for querying it would go like this:

a) find cameras a user has

```
Image.objects.values('camera').filter(users=the_user_in_subject).distinct()
```

b) Filter user images by camera

```
Image.objects.filter(users=the_user_in_subject, camera='camera type')
```

Also if your File model has other fields as well, you can use the `through` option https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thanks for the response. Isn't it a better idea to keep a record of the distinct cameras in another object instead of going through all the images every time?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to query for the cameras anyway? :) The above querysets will produce a single query with a single join (Image and m2m intermediate table are involved). Keeping the cameras on a separate model would add an extra join on top of that (to the Camera model). Edit: Unless of course you want Cameras to have properties themselves!

Comment: There are two tasks. 1- one it just figuring out what cameras a user has. 2- and one is to figure out what images with a particular camera she has. cameras don't have extra properties. I though keeping the (1) on a separate list and updating it when adding new images, would make this more efficient. Isn't that the case?

Comment: so each Image has a camera field. and Images and Users have manytomany relation (through File) as you suggested. Is it a good idea to have a onetomany camera field for User as well?

Comment: No, this would result in duplicate information in the db. You can use related_name https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects to access cameras from the User model (e.g. user.images.values('camera').distinct() assuming the related_name='images'). Please do read the above link carefully, django has a detailed, nice documentation!

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Here is another issue: there are some fields in the File (Which I have as "through" option) and now I need to find Files that their Image has a camera associated with it and also the File has some specific field. Any hints?